# Getting from Canada to Greenland without flying

Tags: budget, canada, transportation, ferries, greenland

Is there a way for me to get to Greenland from Canada without flying? Basically I'm looking for it to be as cheap as possible.

Comment: There are no roads or bridges as Greenland is pretty far from the continent for that. It's also far enough north than even driving up in Canada to catch a ferry (not aware of any service) might be difficult

Comment: In fact, there are no scheduled flights from the US or Canada to Greenland, and I couldn't find any scheduled cruises either. Since southern Greenland is closer to Iceland than it is to any major Canadian city or port, your best bet is probably to travel via Iceland, though if you are planning onward travel thorugh Europe, I'd also try pricing multi-stop trips from Copenhagen.

Comment: @choster:  [Polar Cruises](http://www.polarcruises.com/arctic/ships/expedition-ships/ocean-endeavour-arctic/greenland-and-wild-labrador) does offer a cruise that starts in St. John's, Newfoundland and ends in Kangerlussuaq, Greenland.  Prices start at only 7,995 USD!

Comment: Greenland is so far from everywhere that you can't equate "as cheap as possible" with "not flying".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert $7995 and up is a different route.  The one to Greenland isn't until next year and starts at only $7395.

Comment: @DanNeely:  Good point.  And hey, $600 is a substantial savings!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I wouldn't pass up a 7.5% discount.  OTOH I doubt I'll ever go on one of that ship's cruises either.

Answer (score 9):

[According to Visit Greenland, at the time of writing there are no ferries to Greenland from either Canada nor Iceland nor Denmark.](http://www.greenland.com/en/plan-your-trip/how-to-get-to-greenland/) Indeed Greenland doesn't seem to be an appealing market for inter-country ferries. The linked site nevertheless suggests hopping on a cruise that includes Greenland on its list of destinations, as these are becoming more and more popular. Quoting from Visit Greenland:

> #### By sea to Greenland
>
> There are no ferry connections between Greenland and Iceland, Denmark or Canada. However, more and more cruise shipping companies are choosing to include Greenland on their itineraries, whereby it is possible to begin the voyage from Iceland or go onboard at, for example, Kangerlussuaq. Some shipping companies also sail from the USA and Canada or a country in Europe.

Note that [the country itself does have quite a well developed coastal ferry system that takes you from port to port.](http://www.greenland.com/en/things-to-do/cruises-and-coastal-sailing/coastal-ferry-in-greenland/) There are just no ferries to/from other countries to date.

Comment: For a cost-sensitive traveller like the OP, flying is probably better than taking a cruise.  For example, [Polar Cruises](http://www.polarcruises.com/arctic/ships/expedition-ships/ocean-endeavour-arctic/greenland-and-wild-labrador#rates_52) charges upwards of $7k for a Newfoundland–Greenland cruise.  My gut feeling is that "as cheap as possible" is not very cheap when it comes to Greenland.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree. However the OP mentions they would prefer not to fly to Greenland. Hence why the cruise option.

Comment: as far as I can see, there are no flights from Canada to Greenland according to the first link

Comment: @EdmundYeung99:  good point;  it appears the only way to get from Canada to Greenland without going through another country is via a rather expensive cruise.  Apparently Air Greenland has [attempted to run regular service to North America at least twice](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11068/flights-to-greenland-seasonal-ex-north-america?rq=1) (once to BWI, and once to Iqaluit), but as of this date no such service is running.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert [They're trying again starting summer 2024](https://www.rcinet.ca/eye-on-the-arctic/2023/10/18/air-greenland-to-restart-nuuk-iqaluit-link-in-summer-2024/)